# How to access a property in a public method. "Use of undeclared identifier error"

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

This probably sounds bare bones basic, but I need help. I'm a bit new to objective-c. So I have a void method that that sets a property. How would I use that same property inside of a public method? Here's the code:

.h

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *globalShowKey;
```

.m

```
  +(NSString *)fileStructure{

        NSString *mainDBPath = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:CLIENT_KEY];

        NSString *subDirectory = [mainDBPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:globalShowKey];



        return subDirectory;
    }
```

Could someone please give me an explanation what the best approach to achieve this? I am so close to achieving this! If I am unclear, please let me know.

Comment: You seem to try to access a member of an **instance** in a **class** method. There is no self in class methods.

Comment: sure there is self in a class. of course it isn't an instance but a class pointer

Answer (score 1):

You are using `self` in class method as `+` in method definition indicates its class method and in class method `self` represent `class` not instance of that class.This line is causing trouble

```
   //self represent here class not instance but you need to access instance variable through property
    NSString *subDirectory = [mainDBPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.globalShowKey];
```

use `-` instead of `+` in method as `+` indicates class method and `-` indicates instance method

```
 -(NSString *)fileStructure{

        NSString *mainDBPath = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:CLIENT_KEY];

        NSString *subDirectory = [mainDBPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.globalShowKey];
        return subDirectory;
    }
```

Now call this method on class instance
for eg: if this method is defined in class `Abc` than instead of using `[Abc fileStructure];` make object of class `Abc`

```
Abc *abc = [[Abc alloc] init];
NSString *fileStructure = [abc fileStructure];
```

**EDIT** : You can also make `self.globalShowKey` as constant string if it is not changing througout application like 
`NSString *const GlobalShowKey = @"abc";` //write this after `#import` statements

and than you can append this global key using your previous `class method`

```
 +(NSString *)fileStructure{

        NSString *mainDBPath = [PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:CLIENT_KEY];

        NSString *subDirectory = [mainDBPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:GlobalShowKey];
        return subDirectory;
    }
```

and call it by

`[Abc fileStructure];`

Comment: You're right. That does work. But when I call that class, I am only getting the mainDBPath and not both the mainDbPath and subDirectory. Any ideas?

Comment: are you intializing the `self.globalShowKey`.You can also make global constant instead of instance property like if you want to append @"abc" string than you can make `NSString *const GlobalShowKey = @"abc";`